# Import statements in Python

Tags: python, import, package, python-import

I have reading Learning to Program Python by Mark Lutz. He writes:

> Modules are loaded and run on the first import or from, and only the first. This is on
>   purpose—because importing is an expensive operation, by default Python does it just
>   once per file, per process. Later import operations simply fetch the already loaded
>   module object

So if I have 2 packages a and b and I write the statements:

```
import a
import b
```

What does this actually do? Does this not load the package b? Is a imported twice?

Comment: I'm not sure how any behavior other than importing modules `a` and `b` would be remotely sane.  He's just saying that Python isn't going to import the same module twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are misreading this statement

> Modules are loaded and run on the first import or from, and only the first. This is on purpose

This statement is **not** saying that it will only run the first `import`.  It's saying that for a given module it will only be imported on the first  `import` that references it.  Or in other words Python won't import the same module twice.  It has no bearing on importing different modules

Comment: Oh okay. Could not figure that out. I thought you import one module and done. Can't import any more. It would be a very big bug in that case.